# Displaying C debugger output in VS2012 ?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

So I wrote a POSIX Threads application in C (linux) in which you get as command line args the number of threads , and the filename which the threads will work on.It works.

Now I also need to make it work in windows. 
I've changed all the necessary names and headers , but since I'm trying to do it in VS2012 , I don't know how to get the Debugger output.

printf does not work , obviously , so what can I use instead ?

The code is included in a C++ WinConsoleApp project.

Comment: What do you mean by "debugger output"? Why wouldn't `printf` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`OutputDebugString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, but the VS output window should work only for debugger output. For console output, you should create `Windows 32 Console Application` project.

Other way is to allocate console yourself:

```
AllocConsole();
freopen("CONIN$", "r",stdin);
freopen("CONOUT$", "w",stdout);
freopen("CONOUT$", "w",stderr);
```